# How many lucky usernames are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Yesterday I was at the exam where I had this question (attached).

I didn't know how to calculate the answer, so I took the chance and guessed where I answered the last option.

Does anyone know what the right result is (so I know if my Guess was right or not).

Thanks for your time.

[image]

Question g.

Comment: Why include question f in the post?

Comment: Why are there answers in your own question?

Comment: $\binom{26}{2}\cdot4+26$

Comment: In my view *none* of the answers is correct. Under the extra condition that $4$ consecutives means "not lucky" the third answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a four character user name, we have a condition that three must be identical. Thus, the user name can have at most two unique characters.

---

Case 1: The user name has exactly two unique characters.

The two characters can be selected from the $26$ characters in $\binom{26}{2}$ ways.

Out of these two, one has to be selected to appear three consecutive times. This can be done in $\binom{2}{1}=2$ ways.

Finally, which of these two characters comes first in the user name needs to be decided, which can be done in $\binom{2}{1}=2$ ways.

Thus, the total number of ways is $\binom{26}{2}.2.2=\binom{26}{2}.4$

---

Case 2: The user name can have a single character appearing $4$ times

This is just like the previous case, except that we need to add the cases in which the user name has only one unique character. That character can be selected in $\binom{26}{1}=26$ ways.

Then, the total number of ways is $\binom{26}{2}.4 + 26$

---

Looking at the options, it appears that the question is asking for case 1, which means the third option is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be 1326...because you inclue the word like $aaaa$. This doesnot violate the conditions..